Selecting indexed column returns different order from table design
Using select top 1 * from on the table works
But select top 1 id doesn't. When selecting only the indexed column, returns in the wrong order. Even though, the column id has a user defined clustered index with the purpose of storing new records in a FIFO-like structure, being easier to scan more recent data, since it's at the begining of the table
drop table if exists numbers
create table numbers (
    h char(1),
    id int identity(-2147483648,1) not null
    primary key nonclustered (id),
    index ix unique clustered (id desc)
)
insert into numbers (h) values
    ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), ('h'),
    ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), ('h'),
    ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), ('h'),
    ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), ('h'),
    ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), ('h'),
    ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), ('h'),
    ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), ('h'),
    ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), 
    ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), ('h'),
    ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), ('h'), ('h')
; select top 1 id from numbers -- 1
select top 1* from numbers     -- 50

Is the index 'wrongfully implemented'?
If not, how to achieve the desired functionality? What happened to the indexe's order
being different from the intended with the index definiton?

"If not, how to achieve the desired functionality?" - what "desired functionality" are you referring to?

Using SELECT TOP without ORDER BY always results in undefined ordering - why does this surprise you?

There's no order guarantee when you omit ORDER BY.
